# Latest date from ClassSchedule Table for each class

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a problem with database query?
Here is the Scenario
This is a TeacherClass Table (Parent Table)(id)
[image]
And This is a ClassSchedule Table(Child table)(teacher_class_id is a foreign key)
[image]

I want to find out the the latest date from ClassSchedule Table for each class and order by class_schdule_date(latest date).
(It would be better for me if you write the query in cackphp query syntax.)
Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a straightforward join:

```
select tc.id, max(schedule_date) as max_schedule_date
from TeacherClass tc
left join ClassSchedule cs on cs.teacher_class_id = tc.id
group by tc.id
```

You can select other columns from the TeacherClass table as you like - just add them to the group by clause too.

Note that `left join` is required in case there are *no* scheduled dates for the class, you still get a row for the class (but the max scheduled date will be null)

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution:

```
SELECT 
    c.*, b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT teacher_class_id, MAX(schedule_date) AS maxdate
        FROM classschedule
        GROUP BY teacher_class_id
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    classschedule b ON 
        a.teacher_class_id = b.teacher_class_id AND
        a.maxdate = b.schedule_date
INNER JOIN
    teacherclass c ON
        b.teacher_class_id = c.teacher_class_id
```